# Json reader rootProperty call in sencha touch store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.2

```
   {
    "success": true,
    "message": "Successfully retrieved data for report #1",
    "content": {
            "fields": ["name", "2013", "2012", "2011"],
            "data": [{
                    "name": "1",
                    "2011": 378.4,
                    "2012": 208.95,
                    "2013": 229.92
            }, {
                    "name": "2",
                    "2011": 258.92,
                    "2013": 265.92
            }, {
                    "name": "3",
                    "2011": 242,
                    "2012": 227.98,
                    "2013": 558.13
            }, {
                    "name": "4",
                    "2011": 322.5,
                    "2012": 390,
                    "2013": 282.09
            }, {
                    "name": "5",
                    "2011": 563.88,
                    "2013": 461.1
            }, {
                    "name": "7",
                    "2011": 268.5,
                    "2012": 305.48
            }]
    }
   }
```

this is my json .. I want to read data:[{name:"",..... }] from my store,so I am giving rootProperty: content[0].data but it is not working, can anyone please tell me how to read that data and help me on this issue. Thank you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it rootProperty: 'content.data' working fine.My issue is with url . Thank you